# Boolean value gets transformed to a String

Tags: vuejs2

I have an radio input component:

```
<input
  type="radio"
  :value="true"
  v-on="{
    ...$listeners,
    input: (event) => { someMethod(event) }
  }"
>
```

The method:

```
methods: {
  someMethod (event) {
    console.log(event.target.value === 'true')
  }
}
```

I would expect the value to be a boolean value and not a string because of the `:value=` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You are handling native HTML `input` event, so what you get is native browser event structure.

And `event.target.value` is always a string. Vue has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Yea thought so. So the only way is to check the string value and return a boolean value on that...